# How can I implement the feature for user to select a rating and its highlighted before clicking submit button? also can only highlight one at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css

**this is the image below i am trying to make work. I want user to be able to select a rating then it highlights and stays highlighted then they can be able to submit? here is pic of it**

[image]

Comment: Don't you have any of code to share with us. Please show us your progress then we will be able to do the rest like adding the JavaScript part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out!

```js
var icons = document.querySelectorAll(".rating-icon");
        icons.forEach((btn) => {
            btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                icons.forEach((btn) => {
                    btn.classList.remove("rating-selected");
                });
                var values = e.target.dataset.value;
                window.stars = values;

                console.log("rating: " + values);

                var stars = Array.from({ length: values }, (v, i) => i + 1);

                stars.forEach((star) => {
                    document
                        .querySelector(`.rating-icon[data-value="${star}"]`)
                        .classList.add("rating-selected");
                });
            });
        });

        document.querySelector(".submit").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            if (window.stars) {
                alert(window.stars);
            } else {
                alert("Please select a rating");
            }
        });
```

```css
/*CSS - DONT CARE LOL*/

            body,
            html {
                background-color: #212832;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                height: 100vh;
            }
            .container {
                display: flex;
            }
            .rating-icon {
                background-color: #273039;
                height: 40px;
                width: 40px;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                color: #d3d3d3;
                border-radius: 50%;
                font-weight: 600;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                margin-right: 5px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .rating-icon:hover {
                background-color: #12c958;
            }

            .rating-selected {
                background-color: #12c958;
            }

            .submit {
                background-color: #fb7413;
                padding: 10px;
                border-radius: 50px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                width: 230px;
            }
```

```html
        <div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="rating-icon" data-value="1">1</div>
                <div class="rating-icon" data-value="2">2</div>
                <div class="rating-icon" data-value="3">3</div>
                <div class="rating-icon" data-value="4">4</div>
                <div class="rating-icon" data-value="5">5</div>
            </div>
            <button class="submit">SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
```